# Creating User Define Function to Convert Dates in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I know how to convert to date in SQL Server (T-SQL) but how do I create a UDF so that I can call it each time in my code?

Example 1: The below code will format this 20120428 to 04/28/2012

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), CONVERT(DATE, TEST_DATE), 101) AS MY_DATE
FROM
MEMBER
WHERE ISDATE(TEST_DATE) <> 0
```

Example 2: The below code will format this 20120428 to 2012-04-28

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, TEST_DATE) AS MY_DATE
FROM
MEMBER
WHERE ISDATE(TEST_DATE) <> 0
```

Thank for the input!

Guy

Comment: Actually your first example uses 103 which leads to 28/04/2012 not 04/28/2012.

Comment: As a side note, if you're using pre SQL Server 2012, the filter clause may or may not be evaluated before the select clause. See @AaronBertrand's excellent response to my [question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5312/conversion-of-varchar-data-to-datetime-failing)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the second example you can do this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ConvertDate(@d CHAR(10))
RETURNS DATE
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT CONVERT(DATE, @d));
END
GO
```

But a more flexible approach might be:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ConvertRegional
(
  @d CHAR(10),
  @style TINYINT
)
RETURNS CHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), CONVERT(DATE, @d), @style));
END
GO

DECLARE @d CHAR(10);
SELECT @d = '20120428';

SELECT 
 dbo.ConvertDate(@d),
 dbo.ConvertRegional(@d, 101),
 dbo.ConvertRegional(@d, 103),
 dbo.ConvertRegional(@d, 120);
```

Results:

```
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
2012-04-28  04/28/2012  28/04/2012  2012-04-28
```

If you don't want to continue filtering out bad non-dates from your source table (keeping the ISDATE() in the WHERE clause should prevent the function from having to deal with those rows), you can change the function this way to avoid errors, if NULL is okay as a substitute:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ConvertRegional
(
  @d CHAR(10),
  @style TINYINT
)
RETURNS CHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT CASE WHEN ISDATE(@d) = 1 THEN
      CONVERT(CHAR(10), CONVERT(DATE, @d), @style)
      END);
END
GO
```

In SQL Server 2012, you can do this instead, which does the same thing without having to write your own CASE:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ConvertRegional
(
  @d CHAR(10),
  @style TINYINT
)
RETURNS CHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), TRY_CONVERT(DATE, @d), @style));
END
GO
```

(In fact in SQL Server 2012 you can also use FORMAT() so that you don't have to memorize the style numbers, but since I don't know what version you're using I'll leave that for another day.)

All that said, other than saving a few keystrokes in your queries, this encapsulation is actually going to make your queries perform worse (depending on where they are used). For simple conversions like this it is much better to just perform them inline in most cases.

Comment: Thank you, I have modified the code in the original post to show how I use ISDATE to filter bad dates.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is a great example with perfect flexibilities.
Thanks again!

Guy